# How to deploy an bower based angularjs webapp via FTP

Tags: angularjs, ftp, gulp, bower, filezilla

Sorry for the stupid question but I have never used FTP before. I have a webapp that is `built upon gulp and bower.json and angularjs` **using [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) yeoman generator.** normally running this app locally I would run bower-install and then gulp and then gulp serve but now I want to deploy it to a server using `FTP via fileZilla.`

I know how to upload files there, have everything setup I `can run a simple html page` but I am stumped how to initiate this app there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `gulp build` to pack all necessary sources together.

After that process is done you can upload the contents of the `./dist` folder via ftp.

For making your app accessible you need a simple http server that serves the sources you uploaded e.g. apache, nginx, lighthttp

---

**Edit:**

Assuming you have `linux` as server OS and your app is located in `/usr/local/www/app`, a minimal example apache vhost configuration could look like the following snippet:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/app/
    ServerName server.tld
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have setup apache, my problem is that the remote site is serving html from root directors whereas my html is in /src folder. Can I change that path from fileZilla?

Comment: Could you post necessary Information of your vhost configuration and your directory structure?